# Polygon Segmentation technique

Tags: image-processing, matlab, image-segmentation

I am working on Automated GUI components Segmentation problem. My Images are very simple as it has GUI components such as Buttons, text box and other polygons as you can see in the diagram (a).
Diagram (b) is the hypothetical and desired image of segmented portions.

image A and B respectively 
[image]

- **My approach**:

I have implemented the Watershed transformation in this regard, but the results are not satisfying.
The regions are over segmented and thus are not useful for automation. The results include very large
number of small portions of background image.

Actually, I couldn't get the right bg and fg markers to apply watershed upon.

I have followed this link:
[www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/marker-controlled-watershed-segmentation.html](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/marker-controlled-watershed-segmentation.html)

- **Question** :

  1. How to select appropriate Markers to achieve desired result ?
  2. Are there any better approach to attain desired goals ?
  3. should the similar approach would work for text segmentation ?

Thanks

Comment: I would try the following segmentation aproach: Gray transform. Then start with large median filter to eliminate all smaller details. Then compute color histogram and detect minimas. Maybe smooth histogram before. Segment by thresholding all of the computed minimas.

Comment: @Steffen Thank you for the comment; I have considered this approach but the selection of multiple threshold levels was unmanageable for an automated process. Can you propose any solvent for automating the threshold levels ?

Comment: What do you mean with solvent? I meant detect minimas in histogram, this should be solvable by an algorithm.

Comment: I meant after detecting minimas, histogram thresholding is the part which requires some seed value.I am talking in the context of Algorithms such as Discrete Curve Evolution and etc.